# Docker Compose - Image name

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When you are running a **docker-compose up -d** command, by default the build image is going to take the name of the current folder.

So for example for this **docker-compose.yml** file my image will be named:
**dockersymfony_php** because my current folder is named **docker-symfony** and I indicated **php** for my image in my yaml file

```
php:
    build: ./docker/php
    container_name: symfony
```

Is there a way to override that ?
Like **container_name** to renaming the container...

I know that the command **docker build -t  .** can do it but I need to use my **docker-compose.yml** file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently all you can do is customize the project name (the first part of the name before the underscore) using `-p` flag:

`docker-compose -p COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME`

In the next release you'll be able to use `image` to set the name: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2092

Comment: What version of `docker-compose` supports this? Doesn't work with 1.5.2 build 7240ff3.

Comment: supports which? Setting the project name has always been supported.  The linked issue will be in 1.6.0

Comment: You're right. Maybe I ran `docker` instead of `docker-compose`.

Answer (score 2):

As of Jan 2018, with version 3 of Docker compose you can use container_name to specify the name. An example can be found here https://www.handsonarchitect.com/2018/01/docker-compose-tip-how-to-avoid-sql.html